# Remove first "\" at class name on PHP file that is generated by Thrift

Tags: php, namespaces, thrift

When I use Thrift to generate PHP file without namespace (I want to give namespace after), the same as:

```
//namespace php tutorial //don't use namspace

service Calculator {

   void ping();   

}
```

Thrift will create a Calculator.php:

```
namespace ; //error but no problem, i will give namespace after

interface CalculatorIf {

  public function ping();

}

//problem at "\CalculatorIf"
class CalculatorClient implements \CalculatorIf {
  //thrift code ...            
}
```

Problem is **"\CalculatorIf"**, that mean \CalculatorIf belong root namespace (or no namespace)  when i want to give a new namespace (such as "namespace MyNS;"), it will get error because \CalculatorIf is not belong my new namespace. if **"CalculatorIf" (without "\")** were generated, i will change namespace wittout this problem. There are a lot of place that the same that, terrible! '

I want it is the same below:

```
namespace ; 

interface CalculatorIf {

  public function ping();

}

//this is "CalculatorIf" and not "\CalculatorIf"
class CalculatorClient implements CalculatorIf {
  //thrift code ...            
}
```

Comment: So you are not using a tool as intended and then complain about the results? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No, when i generate thrift file to java file (or something else), it work fine. Because those languages have not a "\" before namespace or class name. only PHP use "\" to specify root namespace, and Thrift always add "\" to head of class path defaultly (maybe, easy for compiler process).

I only want remove "\", or anyway that help all class in file.php is used (by other class) relatively and not absolute.

Comment: Yeah, but that's [the way it is supposed to work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). Your problem solely stems from the approach to *change* the namespace afterwards. You want to do that - fine. But then you are responsible for doing it correctly, nobody else. Or you use the approach suggested in my answer, which should also produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP generation offers a number of options, which `thrift --help` shows you:

```
php (PHP):
  inlined:         Generate PHP inlined files
  server:          Generate PHP server stubs
  oop:             Generate PHP with object oriented subclasses
  rest:            Generate PHP REST processors
  nsglobal=NAME:   Set global namespace
  validate:        Generate PHP validator methods
```

So the solution is to call the Thrift compiler like so:

```
thrift -gen php:nsglobal=wtf  yourfile.thrift
```

which results in

```
interface CalculatorIf extends \wtf\SharedServiceIf {
```

Comment: Thank for your help, I have tried it but this have'nt resolved my problem yet (it still add "\" at head of class path "\wtf\SharedServiceIf" - this is the absolute class path). However, i could change my method to do my work and use your provide.


PS: i want to generate a file that i can move any where by rename "namespace" only. But, now, i have to rename (remove "\") a lot of things.

Comment: "*I want to generate a file that I can move anywhere*" - You can call the thrift compiler as often as you want, with as many different `nsglobal=` as you want. Surely faster than editing the file manually.

Comment: Right, i will do that. I just don't feel comfortable when "class are used in-side namespace relatively but they use absolute path"